# Combining StateT and State monads

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

Lets say I have a function

```
f :: State [Int] Int
```

and a function:

```
g :: StateT [Int] IO Int
```

I want to use `f` in `g` and pass the state between them. Is there a library function for
`StateT (return . runState f)`? Or in general, given a monad transformer with a corresponding monad, is there a library function for it?

Comment: I believe that TomMD's edit is incorrect. I believe that the original `g :: StateT [Int] IO Int` should stand.

Comment: I liked the other changes, fixed the parenthesis ...

Comment: This question seems like what I'm looking for, but the answers are all much more complicated than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325485/combining-statet-io-with-state, which got the job done for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In even more general, what you're trying to do is apply a transformation to an inner layer of a transformer stack. For two arbitrary monads, the type signature might look something like this:

```
fmapMT :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m1, Monad m2) => (m1 a -> m2 a) -> t m1 a -> t m2 a
```

Basically a higher-level `fmap`. In fact, it would probably make even more sense to combine it with a map over the final parameter as well:

```
fmapMT :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m1, Monad m2) => (m1 a -> m2 b) -> t m1 a -> t m2 b
```

Clearly this isn't going to be possible in all cases, though when the "source" monad is `Identity` it's likely to be easier, but I can imagine defining another type class for the places it does work. I don't think there's anything like this in the typical monad transformer libraries; however, some browsing on hackage turns up something very similar [in the `Monatron` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Monatron/0.3.1/doc/html/Control-Monatron-MonadT.html#t%3aFMonadT):

```
class MonadT t => FMonadT t where
    tmap' :: FunctorD m -> FunctorD n -> (a -> b) 
             -> (forall x. m x -> n x) -> t m a -> t n b

tmap :: (FMonadT t, Functor m, Functor n) => (forall b. m b -> n b) 
        -> t m a -> t n a
tmap = tmap' functor functor id
```

In the signature for `tmap'`, the `FunctorD` types are basically ad-hoc implementations of `fmap` instead of using `Functor` instances directly.

Also, for two Functor-like type constructors F and G, a function with a type like `(forall a. F a -> G a)` describes [a natural transformation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.53.5/doc/html/Control-Functor-Extras.html#t%3aNatural) from F to G. There's quite possibly another implementation of the transformer map that you want somewhere in the `category-extras` package but I'm not sure what the category-theoretic version of a monad transformer would be so I don't know what it might be called.

Since `tmap` requires only a `Functor` instance (which any `Monad` must have) and a natural transformation, and any `Monad` has a natural transformation from the `Identity` monad provided by `return`, the function you want can be written generically for any instance of  `FMonadT` as `tmap (return . runIdentity)`--assuming the "basic" monad is defined as a synonym for the transformer applied to `Identity`, at any rate, which is generally the case with transformer libraries.

Getting back to your specific example, note that Monatron does indeed have an instance of `FMonadT` for `StateT`.

Comment: I haven't looked at the Monatron package. I'll have to look closer at that to judge it. I do like your idea of defining a type class for when it does work, can anyone confirm or disconfirm that Monatron does this?

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is a mapping (known as a monad morphism) from a monad `StateT m` to `StateT n`. I'll be using the the [`mmorph`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mmorph/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Morph.html) library, which provides a very nice set of tools for working with monad morphisms.

To perform the `State -> StateT m` transform you are looking for, we'll start by defining a morphism to generalize the `Identity` monad embedded in `State`,

```hs
generalize :: Monad m => Identity a -> m a
generalize = return . runIdentity
```

Next we'll want to lift this morphism to act on the inner monad of your `StateT`. That is, we want a function which given a mapping from one monad to another (e.g. our `generalize` morphism), will give us a function acting on the base monad of a monad transformer, e.g. `t Identity a -> t m a`. You'll find this resembles the `hoist` function of `mmorph`'s `MFunctor` class,

```hs
hoist :: Monad m => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

Putting the pieces together,

```hs
myAction :: State s Int
myAction = return 2

myAction' :: Monad m => StateT s m Int
myAction' = hoist generalize myAction
```

Answer (score 4):

Such a function is not definable for all monad transformers.  The `Cont r` monad, for example, can't be lifted into `ContT r IO` because that would require turning a continuation in the IO monad (`a -> IO r`) into a pure continuation (`a -> r`).

Comment: Didn't think of that. Like you said, this isn't possible for every monadtransformer. So it would require a special kind of connection between the transformer and the corresponding monad then...

Comment: Wouldn't the transformation go the other way? Since the `r` in a continuation type is usually polymorphic, you could just write `(ContT . runCont) :: Cont (m r) a -> ContT r m a`.

Comment: @camccann I was going for a generalized class of transformations (Monad m => m a -> (TransformerOf m) m' a) (abusing notation a bit).  If you try to write an instance for (Cont r a -> ContT r m a), you'll get stuck at the point I described.