# Combining StateT IO with State

Tags: haskell

If I have a function `f :: State Int ()`, is it possible to use it within another function `g :: StateT Int IO ()`? Nesting it with `f = do { something; g }` fails to typecheck with `Couldn't match type 'Data.Functor.Identity.Identity' with 'IO'`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `g = do { something; f }`? You want to use f within g, right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, this operation is usually called "hoisting". For the State monad, it could be defined as

```
hoistState :: Monad m => State s a -> StateT s m a
hoistState = state . runState
```

Unfortunately, it is not defined in the `Control.Monad.State` module.

Comment: See also the [tutorial for the `mmorph` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mmorph/1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Morph.html#g:4)

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Seems like having a type-class for monad transformers with `hoistId :: (Monad m) => t Identity a -> t m a` would be an useful (Haskell98) addition to the base libraries. It'd be just a specialized version of `MFunctor` for the functor `return . runIdentity`.

Comment: @Roman Cheplyaka - this is also called "local effect" in Ralf Laemmel and Joost Visser's "Design Patterns for Functional Strategic Programming" http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0204015

Comment: You can also write this as `hoistState = state . runState`, which is a little less mind-bending to reason about (in fact `StateT . (return .)` is the definition of `state`.)