# How to hide state from functions that call other functions that use that state

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I would like to have some higher level functions in my Haskell program call other functions that eventually call functions that use some state or configuration, and not have to pass the state around all these function calls. I understand this is a classic use of the state monad (or possibly the Reader monad?).

(I'm also not sure if it should be StateT (as in my example below) to enable doing IO, or if results should somehow be output separately.)

At this stage I'm pretty confused by all the tutorials, blog posts, and similar questions here, and can't pick out the solution. Or have I misunderstood the hiding thing?

Here's a small example:

```
import Control.Monad.State

-- Here's a simple configuration type:
data Config = MkConfig {
      name :: String
    , num  :: Int
    } deriving Show

-- Here's a couple of configurations.
-- (They're hard coded and pre-defined.)
c1 = MkConfig "low" 7
c2 = MkConfig "high" 10

-- Here's a lower level function that explicitly uses the config.
-- (The String is ignored here for simplicity, but it could be used.)
fun :: Config -> Int -> Int
fun (MkConfig _ i) j = i*j

-- testA and GoA work fine as expected.
-- fun uses the different configs c1,c2 in the right way.
testA = do
    a <- get
    lift (print (fun a 2))
    put c2
    a <- get
    lift (print (fun a 4))

goA = evalStateT testA c1
-- (c1 could be put at the start of testA instead.)

-- But what I really want is to use fun2 that calls fun, 
-- and not explicitly need state.
-- But this function definition does not compile:
fun2 :: Int -> Int
fun2 j = 3 * fun cf j  
-- fun needs a config arg cf, but where from?

-- I would like a similar way of using fun2 as in testB and goB here.
testB = do
    a <- get
    lift (print (fun2 3))  -- but fun2 doesn't take the state in a 
    put c2
    a <- get
    lift (print (fun2 42))  -- but fun2 doesn't take the state in a 

goB = evalStateT testB c1
```

I want to hide the configuration away from the higher level functions like fun2 in my program, while still retaining the ability to change configuration and run those functions with the new configuration. This is a 'how to do it question' (unless I've got the wrong idea completely).

Answer (score 2):

You can't quite "hide the configuration away" in the type signature, of course: a plain old function `Int -> Int` must be referentially transparent, and so it can't also depend on or accept some `Config` value.

What you probably want to do is something like:

```
fun2 :: Int -> State Config Int    -- An `Int -> Int` that depends on `Config` state.
                                   -- Compare to how `Int -> IO Int` is like an
                                   -- `Int -> Int` function that depends on IO.
fun2 j = do
  c1 <- get
  return (3 * fun c1 j)
```

And then wherever you have a `c :: Config`,  you can get the result by something like

```
let result = evalState (fun2 42) c    -- An Int.
```

---

See also [Combining StateT IO with State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325485/combining-statet-io-with-state):

```
hoistState :: Monad m => State s a -> StateT s m a
hoistState = StateT . (return .) . runState
```

Then you can write something like

```
testB :: StateT Config IO ()
testB = do
    -- Fancy:
    result <- hoistState (fun2 42)

    -- Equivalent:
    c <- get
    let result' = evalState (fun2 42) c

    lift (print (result, result'))
```