# Composing State and State transformer actions

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have several `State` monad actions. Some of the actions make decisions based on the current state and other input optionally generating result. The two types of actions invoke each other.

I have modeled these two action types with `State` and `StateT Maybe`. The following (contrived) example shows my current approach.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

import Control.Monad (guard)
import Control.Monad.Identity (runIdentity)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

type Producer      = Int -> State  [Int] Int
type MaybeProducer = Int -> StateT [Int] Maybe Int

produce :: Producer
produce n
    | n <= 0    = return 0

    | otherwise = do accum <- get
                     let mRes = runStateT (maybeProduce n) accum

                     if | Just res <- mRes -> StateT $ const (return res)
                        | otherwise        -> do res <- produce (n - 1)
                                                 return $ res + n

maybeProduce :: MaybeProducer
maybeProduce n = do guard $ odd n
                    modify (n:)

                    mapStateT (return . runIdentity) $
                        do res <- produce (n - 1)
                           return $ res + n
```

I have factored out separating the checks from the actions (thus transforming them into simple State actions) because the check itself is very involved (80% of the work) and provides the bindings needed in the action. I don't want to promote the `State` actions to `StateT Maybe` either, because it poses an inaccurate model.

Is there a better or more elegan way that I'm missing? In particular I don't like the `mapStateT`/`runStateT` duo, but it seems necessary.

PS: I know the example is actually a `Writer`, but I used `State` to better reflect the real case

Comment: `mapStateT` is perfectly fine, IMO. I'd just use `Just . runIdentity` as its argument.

Comment: Roughly the same question (though more theoretical): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138671/combining-statet-and-state-monads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to promote the `State` actions to `StateT Maybe` either, because it poses an inaccurate model.

What do you mean by "promote"?  I can't tell which of these you mean:

1. Rewrite the definitions of the `State` actions so that their type is now `StateT Maybe`, even though they don't rely on `Maybe` at all;
2. Use an adapter function that transforms `State s a` into `StateT s Maybe a`.

I agree with rejecting (1), but to me that mean either:

- Go for (2).  One useful tool for this is to use the [`mmorph` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph) ([blog entry](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/03/mmorph-100-monad-morphisms.html)).
- Rewrite the actions from `State s a` to use `Monad m => StateT s m a`.

In the second case, the type is *compatible* with any Monad `m` but does not allow the code to assume any specific base monad, so you get the same purity as `State s a`.

I'd give `mmorph` a shot.  Note that:

- `State s a` = `StateT s Identity a`;
- `hoist generalize :: (MFunctor t, Monad m) => t Identity a -> t m a`;
- And that specializes to `hoist generalize :: State s a -> StateT s Maybe a`.

---

**EDIT:** It's worth nothing that there is an isomorphism between the `State s a` and `forall m. StateT s m a` types, given by these inverse functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.Morph
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Identity

fwd :: (MFunctor t, Monad m) => t Identity a -> t m a
fwd = hoist generalize

-- The `forall` in the signature forbids callers from demanding any
-- specific choice of type for `m`, which allows *us* to choose 
-- `Identity` for `m` here.
bck :: MFunctor t => (forall m. t m a) -> t Identity a
bck = hoist generalize
```

So the `Monad m => StateT s m a` and `mmorph` solutions are, effectively, the same.  I prefer using `mmorph` here, though.

Comment: Yes, by "promote" I was refering to (1). The `Monad m => StateT s m a` is a neat trick though not obvous and I feel slightly misleading from API stand point. Of course it totally makes sense - "I'm not dependent on the type of the inner monad". `mmorph` looks like the right tool for the job, thanks.

Comment: "The `Monad m => StateT s m a` is a neat trick though not obvous and I feel slightly misleading from API stand point."  I agree it's less clear but I'd say it's, strictly speaking, *not* misleading, because the type would be **isomorphic** to `State s a`.  See my edit to the answer.